# AutoComplete get all data from array and not just one who contain typed letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

```
var cache = {};
$( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var term = request.term;
        if ( term in cache ) {
            response( cache[ term ] );
            return;
        }

        $.getJSON( "/profile/skills-list", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
            cache[ term ] = data;
            response( data );
        });
    }
});
```

With this code (example from jQuery UI Autocomplete) I get all data from array and not just data that contain letter I typing in input field. When I try this example on jQuery site it is work fine.

Why is that happens? What I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cache = {};
$( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var term = request.term;

        $.getJSON( "/profile/skills-list", function( data, status, xhr ) {
            var skills = [];
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                if (data[i].indexOf(term) != -1)
                {
                    skills.push(data[i])
                }
            });
            response( skills );
        });
    }
});
```

Romy has been right. I was get all data from server and on server-side don't exist functionality to check values. So in that reason i was need to check for string position in each value of given array in JavaScript..

Answer (score 1):

The code given seems to be just fine. Are you sure the keyword filtering is working fine in the server-side? It might be that the server-side code is not filtering results based on the keyword in the input field.